# How many uranium-238 atoms are left after 1.338 x 10^10 years?

Tags: exponentiation

The half-life of uranium-238 is about 4.46 x 10^9 years.  How many will there be after 1.338 x 10^10 years?  How can I figure this out?  I know it's exponential, but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you find the number of half lives in $1.338 \times 10^{10}$ years. That is 3. After every half life, the amount of uranium will halve. So there will be $\frac{1}{2^3}$ as much uranium-238 left.

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников No it's right

Comment: It just so happened that in this case it is perfect x3. If it was not...

Answer (score 0):

Let X0 = the number of atoms at time t =o. Then dx/dt = -kt is the differential
equation which governs the decay rate. When t = 4.46*10^9, the value of x0 will
have decreased to 1/2 its value, or X0/2. The solution to the differential
equation is: x(t) = X0*e^(-kt). Substitute t=4.46*10*9 and x(t) =  X0/2 to 
evaluate k. Then, for t =1.338*10^10, just plug it into the solution of the
differential equation.   Edwin Gray